# Unix decides about the type of a file looking for magic files at fixed offsets. How can it do so reliably?

Tags: file-types

From https://linux.die.net/man/1/file:

> The magic tests are used to check for files with data in particular fixed formats. The canonical example of this is a binary executable (compiled program) `a.out` file, whose format is defined in `#include <a.out.h>`
>   and possibly `#include <exec.h>` in the standard include directory. These files have a 'magic number' stored in a particular place near the beginning of the file that tells the UNIX operating system that the file is a binary executable, and which of several types thereof. The concept of a 'magic' has been applied by extension to data files. Any file with some invariant identifier at a small fixed offset into the file can usually be described in this way. The information identifying these files is read from the compiled magic file `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc`, or the files in the directory `/usr/share/misc/magic` if the compiled file does not exist. In addition, if `$HOME/.magic.mgc` or `$HOME/.magic` exists, it will be used in preference to the system magic files. If `/etc/magic` exists, it will be used together with other magic files.

Fair enough. So if, by coincidence, a text file happens to contain a 'magic number' specific to, for example, an `mp4` video at an appropriate offset… Will double-clicking such a text file result in a video player being launched instead of a text editor?

Comment: You might find polyglot files interesting (look up PoC||GTFO).

Answer (score 2):

It depends - your desktop may index files by looking at their MIME-type using `file`.  Or it may simply look at the file-suffix and believe that (see for example *[A Quick Reference to File Extensions and MIME Types](https://www.thoughtco.com/file-extensions-and-mime-types-3469109)*
).

In any case, the video player will make its **own** checks, to ensure that the file loads correctly, and only a naive implementation will just look at the first few bytes.

The `file` program uses a mixture of information (including weights for the measures it takes).  An mpeg4 file has a lot of information which `file` may not use (or need).  See for example *[MPEG-4 Part 14 Audio (M4A,M4B,M4P) Format & Recovery Example](http://www.file-recovery.com/m4a-signature-format.htm)*, and *[MP4 Signature Format: Documentation & Recovery Example](http://www.file-recovery.com/mp4-signature-format.htm)*